# Forwarding tables and longest prefix matching rule

Tags: router, forwarding

Just out of curiosity, let's say I have a forwarding table in an IP router that looks like this:

```
134.50.56.0/22    Interface 4
134.50.60.0/22    Interface 3
192.53.40.0/23    Interface 2
default           Interface 1
```

The router have the following incomming datagrams to deal with:

```
1) 134.50.63.9
2) 134.50.57.13
3) 134.50.52.3
4) 192.53.40.6
5) 192.53.56.7
```

Does the forwarding plane use the longest prefix matching rule here to determine on which interface the datagram should be forwarded?

Then datagram 1 should be sent to interface 3, 2->4, 3->4, 4->2 and 5->2...? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, datagrams 3 and 5 will be send to the default gateway through interface 1, because there is no subnet route to these destinations.

Check out the output of [sipcalc](http://www.routemeister.net/projects/sipcalc/):

```
$ sipcalc 134.50.56.0/22
-[ipv4 : 134.50.56.0/22] - 0

[CIDR]
Host address            - 134.50.56.0
Host address (decimal)  - 2251438080
Host address (hex)      - 86323800
Network address         - 134.50.56.0
Network mask            - 255.255.252.0
Network mask (bits)     - 22
Network mask (hex)      - FFFFFC00
Broadcast address       - 134.50.59.255
Cisco wildcard          - 0.0.3.255
Addresses in network    - 1024
Network range           - 134.50.56.0 - 134.50.59.255
Usable range            - 134.50.56.1 - 134.50.59.254
```

The 3rd datagram, with IP address 134.50.52.3, is not within the range of this network, and this is the same for packet n°5.

An interesting reading is Evan answer at [How does ipv4 subnetting works](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work).

Comment: Petrus: is there a quick way to calculate the network range?

Comment: @LasseAKarlsen: it's just a logical AND between address and netmask. Do it manually or with an ip calculator.